# Bad Request creating Automation Account in Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to create a new AutomationAccount using Python SDK. There's no problem if I get, list, update or delete any account, but I'm getting a BadRequest error when I try to create a new one.

Documentation is pretty easy: [AutomationAccountOperations Class > create_or_update()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-automation/azure.mgmt.automation.operations.automationaccountoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-automation-operations-automationaccountoperations-create-or-update)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.automation import AutomationClient

credential = AzureCliCredential()

automation_client = AutomationClient(credential, "xxxxx")
result = automation_client.automation_account.create_or_update("existing_rg", 'my_automation_account', {"location": "westeurope"})
print(f'Automation account {result.name} created')
```

This tiny script is throwing me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\deploy.py", line 10
  result = automation_client.automation_account.create_or_update("*****", 'my_automation_account', {"location": "westeurope"})
  File "C:\Users\Dave\.virtualenvs\new-azure-account-EfYek8IT\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\automation\operations\_automation_account_operations.py", line 174, in create_or_update
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error, error_format=ARMErrorFormat)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (BadRequest) {"Message":"The request body on Account must be present, and must specify, at a minimum, the required fields set to valid values."}
Code: BadRequest
Message: {"Message":"The request body on Account must be present, and must specify, at a minimum, the required fields set to valid values."}
```

I've tried to use this method (create_or_update) on a different sdk like powershell using same parameters and it worked.

Some thoughts?

Comment: So I'm just scrolling the docs you linked, one thing I notice, for the `AutomationAccountCreateOrUpdateParameters` class as the last parameter: `name`, `tags` and `sku` are all listed as "required" in addition to `location` which you provide. Is it possible those need to be included in your request as well?

Comment: Solved! Those params are not required (doc says are required but are optional in code) but `sku` seems to be the key. I've filled the `sku` field and now is creating the AutomationAccount. Thanks @UpQuark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution is setting the Azure SKU parameter.**

For some reason is not necessary on Powershell but it is on Python SDK. Now this snippet is creating my AutomationAccount successfully.

```py
credential = AzureCliCredential()

automation_client = AutomationClient(credential, "xxxxx")
params = {"name": my_automation_account, "location": LOCATION, "tags": {}, "sku": {"name": "free"}}
result = automation_client.automation_account.create_or_update("existing_rg", 'my_automation_account', params)
print(f'Automation account {result.name} created')
```

Docs about this:

- [AutomationAccountOperations Class > create_or_update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-automation/azure.mgmt.automation.operations.automationaccountoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-automation-operations-automationaccountoperations-create-or-update)
- [AutomationAccountCreateOrUpdateParameters Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-automation/azure.mgmt.automation.models.automationaccountcreateorupdateparameters?view=azure-python)
- [Sku Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-automation/azure.mgmt.automation.models.sku?view=azure-python)

Thanks @UpQuark